# Is there any way in Android to disable ripple effect for the entire app?

Tags: android, xml

I tried to use `<item name="rippleColor">#00000000</item>` in my **themes.xml** file, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Use Matieral Component to remove Ripple effect in a View. Create a style for ripple effect

```
<style name="noRippleEffect" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents">
<item name="rippleColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

**Then pass within a View**

```
style="@style/noRippleEffect"
```

Comment: I was asking about how to remove it for the whole app, not just one view :(

Comment: Okey, You need to pass your Application main style with this line.
 <item name="android:selectableItemBackground">@null</item>
 <item name="android:selectableItemBackgroundBorderless">@null</item>
it's Working mine

Comment: that's an interesting idea, but it didn't change anything for me, unfortunately. I tried both with `@null` and transparent color, both `android:selectableItemBackground` and just `selectableItemBackground`. the effect is still there ‍♂️